# Where do I find the ExternalID and Role Sessionname for a role in AWS

Tags: amazon-iam

I am trying to get some parameters from parameter store in AWS

How do I find the following values for a given role?

```
ExternalId

RoleSessionName
```

I know my ARN

Thansk

Answer (score 0):

The External ID is in Trust relationship